# Change specific string in URL with htaccess and regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

Could you please help me to write .htaccess rewrite rule that will rewrite one string in URL to another (in this case user -> profile):

eg: http://my.site.com/index.php/user/194/

It should be like this to work

eg: http://my.site.com/index.php/profile/194/

It should also change all "user" words to "profile", not just the first.

I have tried with the following code but it is not working for some reason:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?profile=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Please assist. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Do you have other rules?

Comment: No, the only code beside this is:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Comment: Without any rules at all, how did `http://my.site.com/user/194/` ever map to anything? Or is there literally a directory called `user` with directories of numbers in it?

Comment: My apologies, the url is http://my.site.com/index.php/user/194/ (codeigniter). I thought that it would not matter since I only need to change one string to another.

Comment: You may want to find a code igniter fix for this instead of tacking on rewrite rules to change this, specifically, so that links are generated like `/profile/` instead of `/user/`.

Comment: I have already done that, the overwrite rule is for the legacy links which are already sent in emails...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using CodeIgniter's built in routes for this:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html